# Using SQL Server 2008 Schema with JPA

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I got a MS SQL Server (2008) database with two schemas, dbo as default for general purpose e.g. authentication and myapp for domain objects. I want to have JPA-Entitys in both Schemas. I use SpringBoot for configuration.

Entitys tables are created in the right schema as they should, e.g. *myschema.job*, but relationship tables, e.g. *Job_Employee* are created within the default schema dbo. How can I set in whicht schema automatically created tables are stored (without changing the default schema as this just shifts the problem)?

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="myschema")
public class Job {[...]
```

My application.yml looks like:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    datasource1:
      url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydb;schema=myschema
      username: SA
      password: ###
    datasource2:
      url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydb;schema=dbo
      username: SA
      password: ###    
  jpa:
      show-sql: true
      hibernate.ddl-auto : create-drop
      properties:
        hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
      hibernate.default_schema: dbo
```

And the datasources are Configured in

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.datasource1")
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.datasource1")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.datasource2")
    public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.datasource2")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        return secondDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: every Collection must be mapped to the right schema as well with @JoinTable annotation.

E.g. in our Case:

```
@JoinTable(schema="myschema")
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(nullable = false)
private List<Employee> employee;
```

This results in a table calles *myschema.job_employee*.